# How to make a dialog but with the ability to set its content with a custom xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog

In my android app, I want to make a dialog box, the kind of one you get from alertbuilders, where you get access to set positive/neutral/negative button click, but I also want to use the `.setcustomview()` to load the content with my xml file.

Does android have a way to do this? I want to avoid making those buttons...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `setcustomview()` method for the AlertDialog.Builder class, but I do see a `setView()` method, if that's what you mean. :)

From my experience, using `setView()` will allow you to set your custom XML layout (though you will still need to inflate it first) without requiring you to recreate / add buttons to your layout. You just need to call the `setXxxButton()` methods before you build.